# How to get bash file to echo differently based on user input?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I'm pretty new at shell scripts, but I would like to write a basic script where the bash file will echo a different line of text depending on the user input. For example if the script asks the user "Are you there?" and the user input is "yes" or "Yes" then the script would echo something like "hello!". But if the user input is "no" or "No" the script would echo something else. And finally, if the user input is something other than yes/Yes or no/No, the script would echo "Please answer yes or no". Here is what I have so far:

```
echo "Are you there?"  
read $input  

if [ $input == $yes ]; then  
    echo "Hello!"  
elif [ $input == $no ]]; then  
    echo "Are you sure?"  
else  
    echo "Please answer yes or no."  
fi
```

However, no matter the input, I always get the first response ("Hello!")

Also, I would like to incorporate text to speech (as I have done with other bash file projects using festival). In other bash files I have done it this way:

```
echo "Hello!"  
echo "Hello!" | festival --tts
```

Is there a way to incorporate this into the if then/yes no prompt above? Thank you in advance, I'm using this to make simple bash files and to help myself learn.

Comment: Use [Shellcheck](//www.shellcheck.net/) to debug shell scripts (also available in the [eponymous package](//packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=shellcheck&searchon=names&exact=1&suite=all&section=all)). It prints a note about the particular issue(s) in your script.

Comment: Also good idea is to run script with `set -x` on top to see diagnostic output.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The main problem is here:

```
read $input
```

In bash, usually, `$foo` is the value of the variable `foo`. Here, you don't want the value, but the name of the variable, so it should be just:

```
read input
```

Similarly, in the `if` tests, `$yes` and `$no` should be just `yes` and `no`, since you just want the strings `yes` and `no` there.

You could use a `case` statement here, which (IMHO) makes it easier to do multiple cases based on input:

```
case $input in
[Yy]es)    # The first character can be Y or y, so both Yes and yes work
    echo "Hello!"  
    echo "Hello!" | festival --tts
    ;;
[Nn]o)     # no or No
    echo "Are you sure?"
    echo "Are you sure?" | festival --tts
    ;;
*)         # Anything else
    echo "Please answer yes or no."
    echo "Please answer yes or no." | festival --tts
    ;;
esac
```

You could wrap the two `echo` statements and the use of `festival` in a function to avoid repeating yourself:

```
textAndSpeech ()
{
    echo "$@"
    echo "$@" | festival --tts
}
case $input in
[Yy]es)    # The first character can be Y or y, so both Yes and yes work
    textAndSpeech "Hello!"  
    ;;
[Nn]o)     # no or No
    textAndSpeech "Are you sure?"
    ;;
*)         # Anything else
    textAndSpeech "Please answer yes or no."
    ;;
esac
```

---

With `$input`, bash replaces this with its value, which is nothing initially, so the `read` command run is:

```
read
```

And `read` by default stores the input in the variable `REPLY`. So you can, if you want, eliminate the `input` variable altogether and use `$REPLY` instead of `$input`.

---

Also have a look at [the `select` statement](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Conditional-Constructs) in Bash.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been looking all over for this simple solution, but couldn't find it. My only other question is how would I make it a loop? For example, make the script keep looping until the user responds "yes" instead of just ending after the given answer. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Santiago make it a  `while true; do...done` loop, with `break` statement right after `echo "Hello!"`.

Comment: @Santiago that is exactly what the `select` statement is for! A `select` statement will repeatedly ask for the user to select one of the available options, and then based on those options you can decide to `break` out of the `select` statement or continue looping. See, example: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Ztp3XGCKtF/

Answer (score 14):

**TL;DR**: fix syntax errors, ensure you actually have non-empty variables in `[` test, and make a function to pipe  through `tee` into `festival`.

As far as printing to screen and outputting to `festival`, I personally would wrap the script into a function and pipe everything to `festival`, with `tee` in between (which sends text both to screen and pipe).

There's three syntax problems to fix, however:

- `read $input` should be `read input`. The `$` symbol dereferences variable in shell scripting (i.e., it `$input` will be replaced with what `input` holds).
- You've no `yes` and `no` variables declared. What you should be doing is string comparison: `[ "$input" == "yes" ]`
- Extra `]]` in `elif`

As for why you get `Hello!` all the time, that's exactly because of first two bullet points. Before `read $input` the variable `input` doesn't exist, so you're only performing `read` (i.e., nonexistent variable `$input` is dereferenced into empty string, leaving only `read` command there). So whatever you type gets stored in the `REPLY` variable which is what `read` uses when no variable name has been given. And because `yes` variable doesn't exist, that gets replaced with empty string too. Thus in reality `[ $input == $yes ]` is treated as `[ "" == ""  ]` which is always true.

```
$ [ $nonexistent == $anothernonexistent  ] && echo "Success"
Success
```

The fixed script should be as so:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
main(){
    read -p "Are you there?" input  

    if [ "$input" == "yes" ]; then  
        echo "Hello!"  
    elif [ "$input" == "no" ]; then  
        echo "Are you sure?"  
    else  
        echo "Please answer yes or no."  
    fi 
}
main | tee /dev/tty | festival --tts
```

Remember to [quote the variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65633/85039) and read up on [difference between `=` and `==` in test command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/168288/85039).

Comment: Can tee be used to pipe cmatrix into festival? ..just don't ask what for.

Comment: @Willtech Well, yes, it can. All the characters `cmatrix` displays seem to be from the portable character set, so I don't see a problem with other locale characters as in the "real" matrix flow. But I'm not sure how `festival` would work with that, it'd be just whole lot of gibberish. But in theory it'd work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

A third approach would be to assign to a common variable for each case, and in the end act upon that variable.
I'm not sure how common this approach is in bash, but in other programming languages it's fairly standard.

Also `shopt -s nocasematch` in conjunction with `[[` for case-insensitive string comparison.
With this also `YES` and `NO` are treaded as valid input.

[shopt](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html)
[[[](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html)

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nocasematch

read -p "Are you there?" input  

if [[ "$input" == "yes" ]]; then  
    msg="Hello!"  
elif [[ "$input" == "no" ]]; then  
    msg="Are you sure?"  
else  
    msg="Please answer yes or no."  
fi 

echo $msg
echo $msg | festival --tts
```